# Is it possible to download an SQLite database to use locally via HTML5 when offline?

Tags: database, html, sqlite, offline

I'm considering building an [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) application that would require downloading an SQLite database from a server and then accessing that database locally for referencing the data while offline.

Is it possible to download a pre-populated SQLite database and access it locally with HTML5? I haven't been able to find any examples or tutorial on this.

My current thought would be to build the site so that it can all be run while offline via the manifest cache files (so far no problem), BUT it also needs to have access to a pre-populated SQLite database downloaded from a server, and that is the part I'm not sure how to handle.

When online, the HTML5 application would need to have the ability to check the server for updates, rebuild the manifest cache and update the database again...

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 and SQLite aren't the same thing. The offline storage and Web SQL features of HTML5 use implementations with SQLite - but not all implementations will use SQLite.

That being said, the short answer would be: no.

You should instead synchronize your data by doing something like.... storing timestamps of updates and shuttling data back and forth via [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (or similar).

Comment: +1 technology mashups are often possible but also often bad ideas when they are not appropriate.  A big clue is when you can't find any examples or tutorials (not a rule but a big clue).

Answer (score 1):

There is [a specification of a Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) that gives an SQL-like interface, but unfortunately it is no longer under active maintenance. However, it is implemented in Chrome, [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) and [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database). Here is [a tutorial on web databases](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/).

A possible alternative, if your database is is smaller than 5 MB (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space) and you can make due with something like an dictionary/array/hashmap, is to use [local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage).

So, if your browser supports local storage the idea is to store your database as a JSON string in local storage (local storage can only store strings) and whenever you need to access the data you load+parse it. You need the following tools:

```
// Test if you browser supports local storage
'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;

// Store value in local storage
localStorage.setItem(key, value);

// Load value from local storage
localStorage.getItem(key);

// Parse JSON to JavaScript object
JSON.parse('{"name":"John"}');

// Convert JavaScript object to JSON
JSON.stringify({"name":"John"})
```

Most modern browsers have native JSON support. For older browsers there is the excellent [JSON-js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: Thanks Kajic. I didn't realize Web SQL (which used SQLite) was dead.  That was critical to my plan.  That's unfortunate, as Web SQL combined with the manifest cache had the potential to allow for pretty sweet HTML5 based mobile apps that need offline functionality.  This HTML5 based solution would be a lot easier than developing android/ios apps.  I can see IndexedDB being useful, but it certainly won't have the power that WebSQL would have brought. :(